# Throwing a checked exception inside a lambda expression javaFX Button

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I have a method that builds a JavaFX stage to call information from the user, to create a new object with their input. Because I want the same method to work for updating and for creating a new object, I have an overloaded method that can either be called with no args, or with the Object as an argument. The no args method creates a new blank object and passes it to the function building the stage, while the other passes on the object it received when the update was called. (redundant, I realize, but it wouldn't change the nature of the problem.) (This is not a duplicate question, I'm not using generics, I actually included my code, and was already given a partial answer, please put this back up so I can get the confirmation of it.)

```
public static Note newNoteWindow() throws UserCancelledActionException{
     return newNoteWizard(new Note(), false);
}

public static Note newNoteWindow(Note note) throws UserCancelledActionException{
     return newNoteWizard(note, true);
}

private static Note newNoteWizard (Note note, boolean edit) throws UserCancelledActionException {
     Stage wizard = new Stage();
     VBox wizardLayout = new VBox(5);
     Scene scene = new Scene(wizardLayout, 715, 800);
     wizardLayout.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
     HBox buttonBox = new HBox(5);
     Button cancel = new Button("cancel");
     cancel.setOnAction(ev -> {
          clear(); //method that clears all the elements of my UI form
          wizard.close(); // closes the stage itself
          throw new UserCancelledActionException("User terminated object addition");
     });
     note.update();
     return note;
}
```

So naturally I want the user to be able to decide they don't want to actually create this object, so I have a button to cancel, and I use a lambda expression to clear the form, close the stage, and because the function that created it has a return type that I can no longer satisfy I have to throw an exception. The problem is I have no idea how to make the lambda throw the exception inside to the function containing the button. As a warning, I am new to java, and while I have seen some advice about wrapping something in an interface, I have never written an interface, and don't know how this would fix my problem.

When I initially wrote the code, I used throws new UserCancelledActionException() (which I wrote just a very basic extension of Exception for now) and I -expected- it to just throw it to the function that builds the stage, so that function has throws UserCancelledActionException, and the two bootstrap methods that call it have throws UserCancelledActionException, so I was hoping that the exception would bubble up the stack to the method call for the bootstrap and I could use a try/catch to handle the cancellation there.

Comment: You can't throw a _checked_ exception from inside a lambda, but you can throw an _unchecked_ exception.

Comment: so you're suggesting if I change my UserCancelledActionException from extends Exception to extends RuntimeException, it would then bubble up the stack to where I call newNoteWindow() and I could encase that in a try/catch (UserCancelledActionException e) there?

Comment: @ShaunH It wouldn't bubble up to "newNoteWindow()" because the lambda isn't called from this method - it's only created in this method.

The lambda is called somewhere inside JavaFX, when mouse events are handled.

It will bubble up somewhere internal in JavaFX. And then the Exception will be logged. Nothing else will change. So you probably won't achieve anything by doing so.